# When do you have to write delta (Δ) and when not (with example)?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have a rather fundamental question on this equation: 
**J = Δm/AΔt = ρV/ r²πt** * (The equation describes mass that goes through a cross-sectional area in a time interval.)

**Why do they write Δ in the middle of the equation expression and leave out the 
Δ in the expression to the very right?**

Is this just a formal thing, i.e. you can put the Δ there but you don't have to
or does it come with an assumption?

In the respective text it is stated
that intitial volume flowing through the pipe is 0. Does this therefore mean that 
because Volume(out) - Volume(in) = Volume(out) - 0, you can leave out the Δ when writing the equation?

And does this on the other hand mean that if there *was* an initial flux through the area that you have to put the Δ there, as in e.g. Volume (out) - Volume (in) = Volume (out) - 2liters?

But doesn't then time (t) have to be "fixed" too?

*where J = flux with respect to mass; 
m = mass, t= time, r is radius, ρ = density, V = Volume, A = area

Comment: Yes, your analysis is correct. But initial time is probably marked as $t=0$. Therefore, the same argument you made for $V$ applies for $t$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! ( and step by step my grasping of the whole thing increases!) :)